# Cannot sync apps between iMac and iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, applications, imac, authorization

On my iMac, in iTunes, I have one app (called "myApp", say) listed on Library > Apps. I want to transfer that app into my iPad. Under Devices > my iPad > Apps, I press "Install" next to myApp and the button label becomes "Will Install", so I expect it will be transferred to my iPad on the next sync process.

When I press the Sync button below, it starts to sync both devices, and right after it show on the status bar (next to the playback buttons) "Determining which apps to install" , I get the following message:

> **The iPad could not be synced because this computer is no longer authorized for purchased items that are on this iPad.**
>
> To authorize this computer for items purchased from the iTunes Store, choose Store >  Authorize This Computer.

So I go to  Store > Authorize This Computer, I type my Apple account password, next to my Apple ID, and iTunes gives me the following message:

> **This computer is already authorised.**
>
> Including this one, you have authorised 3 computers out of your available 5.

If at this point I try to sync again, I get the same message above saying the computer is no longer authorized.

By the way, on my iPad, under Settings > iTunes & App Store, the active Apple account it the same as on my iMac's iTunes.

Comment: you are confusing me :( did you authorize both the ipad and the imac ?

Comment: Did you authorize a computer, even though the error message says the iPad is not authorized? ...it's quite confusing

Comment: Hey guys! I edited the text so it's more clear now. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Rather than try to fix a broken Apple software setup, I shall suggest a third-party solution. I think [iMazing](https://imazing.com) (not free) can load apps onto iDevices without the need for iTunes now.

“Need to install IPA files on your phone? Done!” — https://imazing.com/features/ios-app-management

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.